# Cannot modify $scope inside graph2d on click handler

Tags: angularjs, vis.js

Is anyone using `visjs` with Angular? I am using it but I am struggling to figure out how to access and modify scope variables. Specifically, inside a handler (such as on click) of visjs, I can't seem to change scope variables at all. Funnily, I even tried rootScope and that doesn't work either? I've never had that happen.

I've set up a sample codepen here - as you see inside on-click I am not able to change either `$scope` or `$rootScope`

http://codepen.io/pliablepixels/pen/WwOpmd

Code fragment of click handler:

```
graph2d.on('click',function (prop) {
     alert ("You clicked");
     $scope.myname = "terminator";
     $rootScope.rootmyname="footer";
   });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's good you figured it out but consider using `$timeout` service instead. `$scope.$apply` might fail when digest cycle is already in progress.

So inject `$timeout` and do like this:

```
$timeout(function() {
    $scope.myname = "terminator";
    $rootScope.rootmyname="footer";
});
```

This will still do the same thing as `$scope.$apply` do but in safe manner.

Answer (score 1):

Ah, problem solved. I had to wrap it in `$scope.$apply`. I updated the codepen.